# How to send params when using data from other models to fill in the form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I'm new to Rails. I'm trying to make an app where students can login in and signup for the exam. I have the following models and controllers which are related to that:

Subject has the following columns:

```
t.string  "name"  
t.integer "ects"
t.integer "year" 
t.integer "professor_id"
```

Its relationship with exam: has_one :exam Its relationship with professor:
    belongs_to :professor

Professor has the following columns:

```
t.string  "first_name"
t.string  "last_name"
t.string  "title"
```

Its relationship with exam: has_many :exams Its relationship with subject: 
    has_many :subjects

Exam has the following columns:

```
t.date    "start_date"  
t.string  "department"  
t.integer "professor_id"  
t.integer "subject_id"
```

Its relationship with subject: belongs_to :subject Its relationship with professor: belongs_to :professor Its relationship with signup:

```
has_many :signups
has_many :signupers, through: :signups, class_name: 'User'
```

Signup has the following columns:

```
t.integer "exam_id"
t.integer "user_id"
```

Its relationship with exam: 
    belongs_to :exam 
Its relationship with user: 
    belongs_to :user

I have already connected everything and made a signup button on exam show view which is linked to new_signup_path. Exam start date, subject name and professor's appear in the form when the user is redirected to it. So, the user has to click submit button only.

This is the form:

```
<%= form_for @signup do |f| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :exam do |e| %> 
        <%= e.fields_for :subject do |s| %>
          <%= s.label :name, "Subject" %>
          <%= s.select :name do %>
            <% [[@exam.subject.name]].each do |c| %>
              <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
            <% end %> 
          <% end %>
        <% end %> 
        <%= e.fields_for :professor do |p| %>
          <%= p.label :professor, "Professor" %>
          <%= p.select :first_name, :last_name do %>
              <% [[@exam.professor.first_name + " " +  @exam.professor.last_name]].each do |c| %>
              <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
            <% end %> 
          <% end %>
        <% end %> 
        <%= e.label :start_date %>
        <%= e.date_field :start_date, value: @exam.start_date %> 
      <% end %> 
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary col-md-3" %> 
    <% end %>
```

All the required data appear in the form, but when I submit the form it says that subject in @exam.subject.name is undefined. Then I realized I also need to permit that parameter, as well as professor's name. So I put it in signup_params in signups controller and defined it in new action, but the problem is that it doesn't recognize it (undefined method `subject' for nil:NilClass).

Here is that part of the controller (I have also tried some other options, but it didn't work. This is just the latest one):

```
 def new
   @signup = Signup.new
   @exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id])
   @exam.subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
   @exam.professor = Professor.find(params[:professor_id])
  end 

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new(signup_paramas)
    @signup.user_id = current_user.id
    if @signup.save
      flash[:success] = "You signed up for the exam."
      redirect_to @signups
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  private 

  def signup_paramas
    params.permit(:exam_id, :user_id).merge(subject_id: @exam.subject.id, professor_id: @exam.professor.id)
  end
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to pass subject and professor params to be recognizable.

I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance :)

PS: I also put accepts_nested_attributes_for in exam model.

Comment: the reason for this is that before clicking the submit button , `@exam` is `nil` which is the same as `null` in Java/C#/etc, in your form you're trying to get `subject` field, whenever you see "undefined method for nil:NilClass" remember the NullPointerException in Java/C#/etc

Comment: I have been struggling with that through the entire project. I was able to solve with something.nil? in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the signup params. You have the @exam.subject and @exam.professor which are not instance variables. So they wont be visible in the view. So move it out to something like this.

```
def new
  @signup = Signup.new
  @exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id])
  @subject = @exam.subjects.find(params[:subject_id])
  @professor = @exam.professors.find(params[:professor_id])
end
```

**And in your view change @exam.subject to @subject and @exam.professor to @professor.**

Also as far as I can see this would do for signup params. Since you are not using the subject_id or professor_id I think that would be unnecessary.

```
def signup_paramas
  params.permit(:exam_id, :user_id)
end
```

Comment: I tried to define **@subject** and **@professor** before and put it in the view without **@exam**, but I didn't know how to do it properly. When i hit the signup button (with this code), it says: undefined method subjects for Exam.

Comment: Sounds like a relationship is not defined. Do you have in the professor.rb the has_many :exams and has_many :subjects?

Comment: @TomConnolly I have that relationship. exam.rb (belongs_to :professor,
  belongs_to :subject, has_many :signups). subject.rb (belongs_to :professor, has_one :exam) and signup.rb (belongs_to :user, belongs_to :exam).

Comment: @Aida If the subject has one exam then you could use something like ```@subject = @exam.subject```. Since the exam can have only one subject. If it can have many subjects then your relationship should be subject.rb (belongs_to :professor, has_many :exams)

Comment: @SudharsananMuralidharan Yes, subject can have only one exam. When I put _@subject = @exam.subject_ I am able to access the form, but I get:  Showing C:/ruby/rails_project/app/views/signups/new.html.erb where line #11 raised:
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass, when I submit it.

Comment: @Aida Modify your signup_params method. Remove the merge part. It should read something like ```params.permit(:exam_id, :user_id)``` which is enough in your case. The permit is used merely as a filter, don't include instance variables in it. It expects just the keys to filter.

Comment: @Aida On a side note in case you wanted subject_id and professor_id which can be accessed from @exam. But if you wanted extra params to send you could use something like ```params.permit(:exam_id, :user_id, :subject_id, :professor_id)```. That's the right way to use it.

Comment: @SudharsananMuralidharan I am using: params.require(:signup).permit(:exam_id, :user_id). I tried using this before : params.permit(:exam_id, :user_id, :subject_id, :professor_id), but it doesn't know what what subjet_id and professor_id are.

Comment: @Aida Yeah because you are not sending those params from the form. But since you can access the subject_id and professor_id from the ```@exam``` object in ```create``` right. That makes it easy. If there was a ```has_many :subjects``` relation then you need to pass in the param subject_id that is selected from the dropdown. In your case it makes it really simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

First you're using the `select` form helper in a wrong way,this :

```
<%= s.select :name do %>
 <% [[@exam.subject.name]].each do |c| %>
   <%= content_tag(:option, c.first, value: c.last) %>
 <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Will only render one option(a select list with only one option!!!), that's because the collection only has one element.

Secondly the option rendered will have the text and `value` attribute set to the same value e.g `<option value="john" selected>john</option>` which depending on your requirements is correct or wrong.

To fix the first issue the collection has to have more than one element, as for the second issue you either leave it as is or use a collection like this `[["john",1],["Mia",2]]` , the result of this collection is this html code :

```
<option value="john" selected>1</option>
<option value="Mia">2</option>
```

The second usage of `select` (`p.select` for professor) is even more strange, you can't select two attributes at the same time, if you intended to provide one input for every attribute you must put two `p.select` blocks, if you want to select the "full_name", I think you should do this :

```
<%=p.select :full_name do%>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And in `Professor` class define `full_name` and `full_name=` like this :

```
def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
end
def full_name=(name)
    first_name,last_name = name.split(" ")
end
```

Now to the real issue, I think the issue is in your new action here :

```
def new
  @signup = Signup.new
  @exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id])
  @exam.subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
  @exam.professor = Professor.find(params[:professor_id])
end
```

The new action by convention handles `Get` requests for forms which want to create new resources, the `Post` request is by convention handled with the `create` action, `@signup` is set correct but the others are trying to query the database for an id coming from `params`, what is params for `Get` request ?

It holds the query paramaters so if the url for creating a signup is "http://example.com/signup/new" then it should be like this "http://example.com/signup/new?exam_id=1&subject_id=2&professor_id=4" for `params[:exam_id]` and others to be filled or otherwise they will return `nil` and `Exam.find(nil)` returns `nil` in your case I suppose, I think that's the issue(I guessed you're not putting any query paramaters).

The fix is simple, the new action should be like this :

```
def new
  @signup = Signup.new
  @exam=Exam.new
  @exam.subject= Subject.new
  @exam.professor = Professor.new
end
```

That way the objects are set to empty state so that they get filled by the form.

Now when the user clicks the submit button, by convention the `create` action handles this POST request but ofcourse we have to take care of strong parameters, your `signup_params` should be like this :

```
def signup_params  
    params.require(:signup).permit({:exam => [{:subject => [:name]}, 
                                              {:professor => [:full_name]},
                                              :start_date]})
end
```

This is how we permit nested params in Rails, for every "object" we put a hash with one key, the key name depends on what you pass for `fields_for`, the value is an array containing the attributes that fills this "object", now if some of these attributes are themselves "objects" we repeat the pattern, in our example we have `fields_for :exam` so we put `{:exam =>[exam_attributes]}` and because exam is the only thing in the whole form we only need to fill "exam_attributes", if by a chance there was for example "@signup.date" That we want to accept we would put it like this :

```
params.require(:signup).permit({:exam=>[exam_attributes]},:date)
```

Now "exam_attributes" are in this case "subject" , "professor" and "start_date". "start_date" is a simple field but the others are objects so we repeat the pattern and ... you got the idea.

By the way you forgot `.require(:signup)`, without this your `create` action can accept requests that provide no `signup` object at all which you don't want.

I hope this solves your problem and happy Rails coding .

Comment: I want to automatically fill in the form and when I put new instead of find, the form is empty. I had params.require(:signup) in my last version, but my main problem was that I didn't know how to pass additional params for subject and professor. Thank you for clarifying that for me. I know that select is used for more options and I that I only have one, but I thought it looks better than text_field. I have been struggling with access (how to access attributes from other models and controllers)  through the entire process of this application creation. This form is my final step.

Comment: @Aida the new action should remain as in this answer, what you seek for is on validation errors saving the form data which has another way to do it, I'll go check and return to you

Comment: My form was filled in when I sent params.require(:signup).permit(exam_id, user_id) and when I had @exam = Exam.find(params[:exam_id]), since it knew which exam I'm referring to, but there was I problem with submission because it didn't know what am sending with subject and professor.

Comment: ahhh you want it filled even before first submit, why do you want this ? if you want to give hints for the user then use `placeholder`(html attribute), if this form is actually for updating a resource then `new` should be renamed to `edit` and `create` to `update`

Comment: It's not for updating. I just want user to see exam information in the form and not to be able to change it. This is just for user to be able to signup for the exam. The data about the exam already exist. I also need to send user_id.

Comment: I get this when I submit the form with automatically filled in data: Exam(#75943320) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#27927216).

Comment: @Aida if data about Exam already exist then if you want to let the user select the exam he/she wants to signup for then a `select` input is better from my perspective :) or don't render them as input but as headers and content

Comment: as for the exception you get, I think that qualifies for a new question :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the weirdest exception I've ever seen.  I got the form like I wanted it to be http://prntscr.com/ecq1ci. I'm still working on submitting it.....